# Manage User Secrets for Class Library

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, app-secret

#### Situation

I have 3 dotnet core projects in question:

- Web API
- Worker Service
- Class Library

In the class library, I have a shared EmailService class that I register for dependency injection in both the Web API and the Worker Service.

Both the Web API and Worker Service projects have the same config section for my sendgrid API key, and they are bound to a POCO using the IOptions pattern in the same exact way.  They are both registered with the `AddScoped` method.  But the actual class implementation for EmailService is in the shared class library.  Running locally does not pickup my user-secrets in either the class library (which probably makes sense) as well as the ETL user-secrets.  Both user secrets share the same exact value of json.

#### Problem

When I set my user-secrets for the ETL project and run them locally, the API key I have for my send grid account is not getting picked up because, I think, the class is defined in the class library.

#### What I've tried

I tried adding the same user-secrets to the class library as well, but this doesn't seem to work and I'm assuming that is because there is no appsettings.json in my class library, as probably there shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to add user secrets to your class library because nothing will pick those up. The configuration system actually doesn’t care in what assembly your options POCOs live, especially since Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (which is where the user secrets are loaded) is only *somewhat* related to Microsoft.Extensions.Options (which is what your POCO is for).

Since you are consuming the configuration through the Options pattern, as long as the dependency injection system is configured to correctly provide all the configuration sources for configuring the options, the code in your library shouldn’t worry much.

So if you are having troubles with the user secrets in your two (executing) assemblies, then it’s about how those are configured. Since you have a ASP.NET Core web app and a worker service, I am going to assume that you are using the host builder for both of these projects. In that case, you don’t need to worry much about setting up your configuration sources since the host builder comes with a sensible default that does include user secrets in development mode.

For what it’s worth, if you ever come across the need to configure user secrets as a configuration provider, you should know that the [`IConfigurationBuilder.AddUserSecrets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecretsconfigurationextensions.addusersecrets?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) extension method will usually expect you to pass in an assembly that identifies the user secrets from the project configuration in the `.csproj` file. – If you are using the default host builder, then it will set this up for you and will use your project’s assembly which is usually what you want to do.

As you have found out yourself, there is [an open bug for 3.1](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4007) which will prevent user secrets from working out of the box for the Worker project template. The reason for this is that the underlying project SDK forgot to handle the `<UserSecretsId>` MSBuild property which is used to identify the user projects.

Fortunately, there is an easy workaround for this problem: All you need to do is to add an explicit reference to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` package. The package is already implicitly referenced by the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` which is included by the default in the Worker project template but by adding it again explicitly you are enabling the few magic MSBuild bits to make the project pick up the user secrets properly.

So your project template should look something like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>fb8be4c5-1316-42a7-8c30-3a752ed21c09</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="3.1.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that library cannot have config. Even if it has a config file of DLL's name - it will be ignored. The application(s) are those who can and should have config. Each of the two can have a section for EmailService, will initialize a config class (`IOptions<T>`) and register in the DI container. That's how the service will get it.

appsettings.config

```json
{
  "EmailService":
  {
    "somethingStatic": "abc:
  }
}
```

appsettings.{Env}.config

```json
{
  "EmailService":
  {
    "apiKey": "xyz":
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```cs
services.Configure<EmailServiceConfig>( 
   context.Configuration.GetSection(    
     EmailServiceConfig.SectionName));
```

EmailServiceConfig.cs

```cs
class EmailServiceConfig
{
  public const string SectionName = nameof(EmailService);

  public string SomethingStatic { get; set; }

  public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

EmailService.cs:

```cs
public EmailService(IOptions<EmailServiceConfig> config
{
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is exactly what I've done.

Comment: @JakeSmith: this is the setup I use at work for 15 microservices, so it definitely works (both .NET Core 2.1 and 3.1). So then please explain in more details what doesn't for you.

Comment: I added to my question with a little bit more detail, but essentially, what you say works makes sense that it would.  But I'm trying to figure out why that's not the case for me.  There are existing issues related to user secrets not working with worker services out of the box (https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4007 and https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2743).  So I'm wondering if there was anything else that you had to do to get it working?  Maybe someone else on your team did something to make it work that you are unaware of...

Comment: In fact, they say that this worked in 3.0 but stopped working in 3.1.  Are you sure that some of your 15 microservices are using 3.1?

Comment: This solved an issue I had for the last two days, using IOptions<T> solved my issues. Thank you @abatishchev

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that in 3.1, worker services don't have asp.net nuget package nor user-secret nuget package explicitly referenced, which is what helps user-secrets work.  But after I referenced the user-secrets nuget package as well as I added the following to Program.cs, it started working: [image]